# VS Code starts debugging in integrated terminal instead of debug console for java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal, console, vscode-debugger

Can somebody help me with this. I am getting output in terminal not in debug console.
Here is my Launch json file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
   {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `"console": "internalConsole"` in launch.json, which specifies VS Code **debug console** (input stream not supported) to launch the program.

More information about debugging, please view [Launch args in Java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch).